# SpringBoot &Thymeleaf loop and buttons

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, computer-science

Could anyone spare a moment?

Issue: I would like to iterate over an array in thymeleaf and add a button to it inside a cell or however it can work.

This is what I'm currently working on:

```
<table>
   <tr th:each="description : ${descriptionList}">
     <td  th:text="${description}"> </td>
     <td  th:each="id : ${idList}">  </td>
     <td  th:text="${id}">
     <td th:each="id : ${idList}">
       <form action="/deletewish" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="email" th:value="${email}">
         <input type="hidden" name="wish_id" th:value="${id}">
         <button type="submit"> Delete </button>
       </form>
      </td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Issue here is that its adding the button correctly, but its also adding buttons equal to amount of iterations.

Is there a solution to iterate once? I'm having real trouble working the syntax here.

I need a table with 1 row and 3 columns with the following info: Description, ID and a delete button.

Thank you for your time.

I tried changing table size and tried different syntax approaches to the thymeleaf loop, but this solution was the best one I found yet.

Comment: It looks as if you have two separate Java lists - one used by `${descriptionList}` and one used by `${idList}`. What is the relationship between these two lists? Perhaps what you need is a single Java list, where each object in the list contains all the data needed for one table row. Then you only need one iterator (at the `<tr>` level) and your Thymeleaf becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example which can help you out. Given the class `User`,

```
class User {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    // other data that is desired
    // setters and getters omitted
}
```

**In the spring controller**

You would have something like a list of users, as such `List<User> specialUsers` and you would add it to the model, `model.add("users", specialUsers);`.

**In the appropriate html page, using thymeleaf**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Operation(s)</td>
    </tr>
<th:block th:each="user : ${specialUsers}"> <!-- Looping each user in the list specialUsers-->
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
        <td>
            <form th:action="@{/user/delete}">
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${user.id}">
                <input type="submit" value="delete">
            </form>
        </td>
    <tr>
</th:block>
</table>
```